# how to "execute" make file

Tags: file, makefile, execute

I tried to use a make file in code::blocks but I am doing it wrong. I have the version installed with the compilers included. http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/10.05/Windows/codeblocks-10.05mingw-setup.exe/download. What do I do with the make file? It starts with:

```
CC=gcc
```

best, US

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You don't tend to execute the make file itself, rather you execute `make`, giving it the make file as an argument:

```
make -f pax.mk
```

If your make file is actually one of the standard names (like `makefile` or `Makefile`), you don't even need to specify it. It'll be picked up by default (if you have more than one of these standard names in your build directory, you better look up the `make` man page to see which takes precedence).

Answer (score 34):

As paxdiablo said `make -f pax.mk` would execute the pax.mk makefile, if you directly execute it by typing ./pax.mk, then you would get syntax error.

Also you can just type `make` if your file name is `makefile` or `Makefile`.

Suppose you have two files named `makefile` and `Makefile` in the same directory then `makefile` is executed if `make` alone is given. You can even pass arguments to makefile.

Check out more about makefile at this Tutorial : [Basic understanding of Makefile](http://story-of-a-programmer.blogspot.com/2015/04/makefile-tutorial.html)